# Philosophers friendly TCS theorem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I understand that it is a naive and very general question. I would like to know when does a theorem of theoretical computer science become interesting to professional philosophers? I understand that the question whether P != NP is pretty interesting to philosophers. Now let's take the conjecture about the existence of one way functions. Is there any philosophical implications of the existence of one way functions?

Comment: You want to know when *philosophers* find TCS topics interesting, thus you should ask them, not theoretical computer scientists. I think the question is off-topic. It also suffers from not being constructive.

Comment: Although I agree with Kaveh, this could interest you: http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1791

Comment: I agree with Kaveh that this type of question may be better directed at philosophers. Also, it is hard to predict what topics will interest another crowd. Several logicians either had philosophical backgrounds or invested significant effort in interesting philosophers in their work. I this some outreach is often behind the scenes of interest from another field.

Comment: If your question is the last sentence, then this is not the site to ask it.  If I discount this question as off-topic, then the rest appears to be too unspecific to elicit good answers.  Please read the [faq#dontask].

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: nice link, make it an answer?

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi: too late, Martin Schwarz beat me to it ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: a few easy upvotes lost :-D :-D

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre: oh, sorry! I didn't click on your arXiv link, so I didn't notice! If you post your answer as well, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @MartinSchwarz: no problem, information matters, not reputation.

Comment: If we migrate to http://philosophy.stackexchange.com it might be a first for this site :)

Comment: Closed the question as off-topic, please check the [faq] for the scope of this site. You may want to post this on [philosophy.se]. (I don't migrate it as I am not familiar with that site.)

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in Scott Aaronson's recent paper *[Why Philosophers Should Care About Computational Complexity](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/philos.pdf)*, to appear in Computability: Gödel, Turing, Church, and Beyond, edited by B. J. Copeland, C. Posy, and O. Shagrir, MIT Press, 2012. ECCC TR11-108, arXiv:1108.1791.